# Enter div value inside of the last focused input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this keyboard that I has build with HTML and CSS and I am trying to figure out how to enter a key (div) letter when is pressed. I need to put this letters inside of the last focused input field.

This is what a have by now:

```
//Here I enter the characters (key letters) in the last focused field
$("div.key").click(function(e) {

    //Here I get the last focus
    var lastFocused;
    lastFocused = $('#registration-area').find('input.item').focus();

    //Here I enter the pressed keys
    var current_text = lastFocused.val();
    var cursor_position = lastFocused.selectionStart;
    var new_text = $(this).text();
    current_text = [current_text.slice(0, cursor_position), new_text, current_text.slice(cursor_position)].join('');
    lastFocused.val(current_text);
    lastFocused.focus();

});
```

This is part of the HTML:

```
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" required/>
<input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" required/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="key-row" style="width: 1040px;">
        <div id="k-a" class="key key-btn">a</div>
        <div id="k-s" class="key key-btn">s</div>
        <div id="k-d" class="key key-btn">d</div>
        <div id="k-f" class="key key-btn">f</div>
        <div id="k-g" class="key key-btn">g</div>
        <div id="k-h" class="key key-btn">h</div>
        <div id="k-j" class="key key-btn">j</div>
        <div id="k-k" class="key key-btn">k</div>
        <div id="k-l" class="key key-btn">l</div>
        <div id="k-ñ" class="key key-btn">ñ</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If someone can please tell me what I am doing wrong I will really appreciate it.

Comment: can you add also html part of code?

Comment: Yes of course. I already updated my question :)

Comment: Your jQuery object, formed from `$('#registration-area').find('input.item')` features at least two elements that aren't in your posted HTML, I can see neither the element with `id="registration-area"` *or* the `<input class="item">` element(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is basic solution please check it and update/ edit/ change/ validate for your needs.

```js
var lastFocused;
$(".item").focusout( function(e) {
  lastFocused = e.target;
});

//Here I enter the characters (key letters) in the last focused field
$("div.key").click(function(e) {

    //Here I enter the pressed keys
    var current_text = lastFocused.value;

   console.log('1: '+current_text);
   
    var cursor_position = current_text.length; //lastFocused.selectionStart;
 // here I just count current value lenght insted selectionStart for fixing add new char to input on  correct place for input email type
    var new_text = $(this).text();
    
    current_text = [current_text.slice(0, cursor_position), new_text, current_text.slice(cursor_position)].join('');
    
    lastFocused.value = current_text;
    lastFocused.focus();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="email" class="item" required/>
<input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="email" class="item" required/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="key-row" style="width: 1040px;">
        <div id="k-a" class="key key-btn">a</div>
        <div id="k-s" class="key key-btn">s</div>
        <div id="k-d" class="key key-btn">d</div>
        <div id="k-f" class="key key-btn">f</div>
        <div id="k-g" class="key key-btn">g</div>
        <div id="k-h" class="key key-btn">h</div>
        <div id="k-j" class="key key-btn">j</div>
        <div id="k-k" class="key key-btn">k</div>
        <div id="k-l" class="key key-btn">l</div>
        <div id="k-ñ" class="key key-btn">ñ</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Thanks! Just one thing, when using input type="email" for some strange reason it enter the characters backwards. Do I must change something?

Comment: please check now, i did small changes for that, you can adjust more for your needs. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is to keep in "memory" what is the last focussed field.

```
lastFocused = $('#registration-area').find('input.item').focus();
```

The above line will actually focus **the first** `.item` in collection... As opposed to get you the last "previously" focussed one. So that is the first issue.

I suggest you to remove the *«Here I get the last focus»* part, which is wrong, by this (outside the click handler):

```
var lastFocused;
$('#registration-area input.item').on('focus',function(){
  lastFocused = $(this);
});
```

And then, assuming what's left from your function below is working... (about the cursor position... Which I'm unsure...):

```
$("div.key").click(function(e) {
  var current_text = lastFocused.val();
  var cursor_position = lastFocused.selectionStart;
  var new_text = $(this).text();
  current_text = [current_text.slice(0, cursor_position), new_text, current_text.slice(cursor_position)].join('');
  lastFocused.val(current_text);
  lastFocused.focus();
});
```

Try it. ;)